# Is $dq_{rev} - dq_{irrev} = dw_{irrev} - dw_{rev}$ is negative

Tags: thermodynamics

I found a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24518/formula-of-entropy-change/24561#24561)

In this it is written that  $dq_{rev} - dq_{irrev} = dw_{irrev} - dw_{rev}$ is negative .

After that they concluded that heat in a reversible process is more. But how can it be possible as work done in a irreversible process is always negative.

Answer (score 1):

Full explanation in the picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this will not the case when pressure and volume both increases

Comment: See the updated answer

Comment: In first case work is positive for both rev and irrev

Comment: @hey you were using chemistry sign scheme. Note that sign scheme for thermodynamics in physics and chemistry are different. Messing up with them can be dangerous in jee.